# Packet received in NIC not read via socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have opened an UDP socket to listen to incoming packet. I could see in the wireshark log the packets reaching the NIC. But the same is not available when reading via Socket. The 'netsatat ' command shows the port number is listened for the any incoming UDP messages. The socket reader keeps on waiting . I have checked using Java and C, in Linux(ubuntu) environment. I can see the Identification value for received IPV4 packet is 0.  Is this value can play any role for a socket to read the data ?
My C code for reading the socket

```
int sock, n, nr;
socklen_t fromlen;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in from; 
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sock < 0)
 printf("Can not create socket in server\n");
memset(&server, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(5555);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while(1) {       
    printf("Waiting to receive\n");
    n = recvfrom(sock, &nr, sizeof(nr), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &fromlen);
    printf("I have received");
}
```

Please find the wireshark trace http://imgur.com/Au9BeS1

Comment: It's impossible to say anything without seeing what you do. Please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to show us.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg added the code and link to trace. please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
if(bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

This will only set `fromlen` is the `bind` call *fails*. And since `fromlen` is not properly initialized, it will contain a seemingly random value that is not valid for `recvfrom`.

Comment: The bind seems to be working fine. I am able to receive IP packets with Flag, Don't Fragment set as 0 but for Don' Fragment=1 the packet reaches the Ethernet but not reaching the application. Is there any good way to debug this? The packet length in IP is 820 the MTU size of my eth0 is 1500

Comment: @vasanthmahadevan Yes, the `bind` call may work, but then `fromLen` will _not_ be set. It might be hard to see because of the indentation, or rather the _lack_ of indentation. Also, if `bind` fails (as well as the `socket` call) then you should not continue like nothing happened.